# How would I build a simple php hook system that works like this?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to build a hook system very similar to the one that Drupal uses. With Drupal you can simply name a function a certain way and it will automatically be invoked as a hook if the module is enabled.

I have looked at the other answers here on Stackoverflow, but none of them really give an answer of how to build this type of feature into a PHP application.

Comment: Look at Drupal and reverse engineer it?

Comment: @Paul I have actually been doing that, but Drupal has quite a bit more functionality than I actually need, and it is not real clear what is actually handling the Hook system.

Answer (score 8):

This is how drupal does it, and how you can do it.
Using string concatenation with name convention.
With function_exists() and call_user_func_array() you should be all set.

Here are the two internal drupal functions that make the trick (module.inc)

```
function module_invoke() {
     $args = func_get_args();
     $module = $args[0];
     $hook = $args[1];
     unset($args[0], $args[1]);
     $function = $module .'_'. $hook;
     if (module_hook($module, $hook)) {
     return call_user_func_array($function, $args);
  }
}

function module_hook($module, $hook) {
    return function_exists($module .'_'. $hook);
}
```

Therefore, you only need to invoke

```
module_invoke('ModuleName','HookName', $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

which will finally call

```
ModuleName_HookName($arg1,$arg2,$arg3);
```

Comment: I don't know why you were modded down, I was too - so I gave you an up-vote.

Answer (score 3):

You could use PHP's [`get_defined_functions`](http://php.net/get_defined_functions) to get an array of strings of function names, then filter those names by some predefined format.

This sample from the PHP docs:

```
<?php
function myrow($id, $data)
{
    return "<tr><th>$id</th><td>$data</td></tr>\n";
}

$arr = get_defined_functions();

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Outputs something like this:

```
Array
(
    [internal] => Array
        (
            [0] => zend_version
            [1] => func_num_args
            [2] => func_get_arg
            [3] => func_get_args
            [4] => strlen
            [5] => strcmp
            [6] => strncmp
            ...
            [750] => bcscale
            [751] => bccomp
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => myrow
        )

)
```

It's kinda a sketchy technique when compared to a more explicit hook system, but it works.

Comment: +1. And with a side-note: there's also https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP which you could use complementary to this. Actually, I think in a clean design, you'd only use aspect-oriented programming, without this hack with "defined functions", but I don't think the OP is that advanced. Nevertheless, it's a nice good-to-know for other readers. You do need at least a VPS to use this, as the AOP extension is not part of the standard distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Drupal internals, but it probably does it using Reflection:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

You would include the PHP page that contains the hook functions, then use reflection to find functions or class methods that match a certain naming convention, then save function-pointers to call those functions when appropriate (such as events in a module's lifecycle).

Comment: I am reading the page you provided, not sure why someone would down vote you without leaving a comment explaining. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use function exist? The developer could name the function in a certain way, and the hook codes just check that it exist then call them